# Different compilers behavior for template specialization

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, template-specialization

I discovered different compilers behavior when trying to specialize a template. Here is the minimum code that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B>
struct foo {
   static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename B>
struct foo<int, B> {
   static const bool value = !foo<B, B>::value;
};

int main() {
   std::cout << foo<int, int>::value << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I have general template with two parameters and specialized template for first `int` type parameter. When using the [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c593d03872c4bb7) compiler I get

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'const bool foo<int, int>::value':
main.cpp:10:30:   recursively required from 'const bool foo<int, int>::value' 
main.cpp:10:30:   required from 'const bool foo<int, int>::value'
main.cpp:14:32:   required from here 
main.cpp:10:30: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
    static const bool value = !foo<B, B>::value;
```

since compiler used `value` from specialized version and infinite recursion is obtained. I get

```
Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant
Error   C2065   'value': undeclared identifier
```

for MSVC. But with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf061c1d16069b03) or zapcc, the code compiles without errors. What is the reason? What is the correct behavior in this case according to the standard or is the behavior undefined?

Comment: clang is not using the value from the primary template, which would definitely be incorrect. I tried changing the primary template's value from `false` to `true`, and the program result was still `1`. Probably clang is using the zero-initialized value.

Comment: @aschepler, Dmytro: Who wants to file the bug report then? :-)

Comment: From my understanding, the compiler should look at the second form to resolve `foo<int, int>::value`, which should result in a diagnostic.  So g++ and MSVC are correct.     You can address the problem by explicitly specialising `foo<int, int>`  e.g. template<> struct foo<int, int> { static const bool value = whatever;};

Comment: @aschepler, you're right! My interpretation of clang behavior is no correct. Really looks like  zero-initialized value.

Comment: You get the same overall results (though different error messages in the case of g++) without templates: `struct bar { static const bool value = !bar::value; };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a language lawyer, but this should *not* compile. You're trying to initialize a value with itself at compile-time. I would guess this is a clang bug. Actually, I don't see why GCC should be following a recursion path like that if it hits a cycle.

By the way, MSVC [tells you](https://godbolt.org/z/1orC3P) (GodBolt):

```
<source>(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'foo<int,int>' being compiled
```

which is the right catch. For once, MSVC outshines the other compilers... :-P

**edit:** @aschepler notes that we [get](https://godbolt.org/z/XQj-KM) (GodBolt) the same behavior even without templates:

```
struct bar { static const bool value = !bar::value; };
```

**another edit**:  It seems that until a few years ago this was sort-of valid code, due to "language lawyer sophistry". You see, the standard used to say (Section 6.6.2 [basic.start.static] paragraph 2):

> Variables with static storage duration ...  shall be zero-initialized... before any other initialization takes place.

and clang took that to mean that first you zero-initialize everything, then you consider the static-duration initializations - which means `bar::value` is implicitly `decltype(bar::value) { 0 }` before its own explicit initialization. This was [changed following Defect Report 2026](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2026).

<sub>The credit for pointing this out goes to [Richard Smith](http://mailto:richard-llvm@metafoo.co.uk).</sub>

Comment: gcc is issuing a diagnostic, which is all that is required.  The standard doesn't dictate the form of that diagnostic, or the manner in which the compiler decides to issue it.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't say GCC is exhibiting buggy behavior. But it doesn't _need_ to try to do 900 instantiations.

Comment: Initializing a value with itself is not always illegal, if zero-initialization applied before dynamic initialization.

Comment: @einpoklum - I didn't think you were suggesting g++ is buggy.  There are plenty of things compilers do that are not required, or for which there are better alternatives.  This seems to be one of them for g++.

Comment: I tried all the compilers available on your link. It looks like a clang bug.